# How to center a div with a specific width and fixed positioning?

Tags: css, html, alignment, css-position, center

I am coding, and trying to center my div horizontally in the middle of the page. It's just a plain div, with nothing inside of it right now. My code is this:

```
#wrapper{
width:500px;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
background-color:#fff;
}
```

Basically, I just want a 500px width white rectangle centered in the page horizontally, that takes up 100% of the page's height.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can assign `left:50%` and after `margin-left (width-of-div / 2)`, in this way you can center div in fixed/absolute position

try this:

```
#wrapper{
   width:500px;
   height:100%;
   position:fixed;
   background-color:#fff;
   left:50%;
   margin-left:-250px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9p83g/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use left 50% and add a margin of negative half the width

```
#wrapper{
width:500px;
height:100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -250px;
position:fixed;
background-color:#fff;
}
```

If you are using this div as a container for a webpage I would recommend taking out position fixed and using `margin: 0 auto;` to center the div